# WCF: How to connect to service by IP:Port

Tags: wcf, service, connection, ip-address, localhost

I need to test WCF service, but have only one computer, so my service and client are running on the same machine. Here is the App.config of WCF Service:

```
<host>
   <baseAddresses>
       <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/MyService"/>
   </baseAddresses>
</host>
<endpoint address=""
    binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
    contract="MyService.IMyService"/>
```

I need to connect to this service from my client by IP, so i tried following:

```
 MyClient.Endpoint.Address = 
        new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(
             new Uri("http://" + IP + "/" + Port + "/MyService"));
```

where IP = "127.0.0.1" and Port = "8000". I also tried to use my real IP address instead of 127.0.0.1 but it doesn't work anyway - client cann't connect to service.

1. Does it possible to connect by IP if I use wsDualHttpBinding, and if yes,
2. What Endpoint.Address should I specify for it

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"? Is there an exception? Post it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an address something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyService
```

You need to put a `:` between the IP address and the port number - not a `/` as you seem to use (at least in your post).